# For loop code not showing

Tags: javascript

Why does nothing showup when I load this forloop?

```
<html>
<body>
<script tpye=text/javascript> 
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 101; i = i + 5)
sum = sum + i;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you didn't output the result in any way?

Comment: Because this code doesn't produce any output.

Comment: lets also mention "tpye" while we are at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to output while looping

```
<html>
<body>
<script tpye=text/javascript> 
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 101; i = i + 5)
{
sum = sum + i;
document.write(sum +"\n");
}
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `div` element to your HTML and append the `sum` using `.innerHTML`.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <script type=text/javascript> 
      var sum = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < 101; i += 5) {
        sum += i;
      }
      document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = sum
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the data, you can try to include `alert();` statements, alternating `HTML DOM`, or `console.log();`, if you are not on the production stage.

See more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp